# What do the brackets in 'turtle.pen()' do? What are they supposed to contain?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So recently I was planning to write a code using turtle graphics and I had a question. What do the brackets in `t = turtle.Pen()` mean? What are they supposed to contain? Please answer in a simplified manner as I am still a beginner at python :)

Comment: You know how `quit()` needs parentheses when you use it to quit the interpreter? Or how `list()` can create a new empty list, but you need the parentheses? Same thing, working the same way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is not a discussion forum. This is not an appropriate place to learn the fundamentals of the language; you should instead follow a tutorial from start to finish. Please do not tell us about being a beginner in the question; it does not add useful information (the answer to the question does not change), we would be able to figure it out anyway, and it is off topic. This is a question-and-answer site; we care about the question, and the answers.

Comment: The reason I recommend a tutorial is because asking a question like this implies a lack of understanding *of the Python language itself*, not of the specific functionality you are trying to use. That's why I made the first comment as well. Tutorials by their nature are usually not specific; the entire reason to follow a tutorial is because *at the beginning, you necessarily do not know what to ask*.

Comment: "If you don't think it's useful information, then I think you can ignore it? " This is **not a discussion forum**, and therefore needs to be used differently. Like with any other community, it is the responsibility of new users to understand how the community works and how to uphold the community norms, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brackets in `turtle.Pen()` don't need to contain anything but there are three optional arguments:

```
shape='classic', undobuffersize=1000, visible=True
```

There are several other `shape` choices (like `"turtle"`) and `visible` can be `False` and `showturtle()` can invoked later, if desired.

Don't confuse `turtle.Pen()` (an alias for the `Turtle` class) with `turtle.pen()`, a method which allows you to get/set attributes of the turtle's pen.  You used one in your title and another in the body of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried a few of those arguments and they work!

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't brackets, they are parentheses. It's a function call without arguments (or in this case, an object instantiation).

What they're "supposed" to contain depends entirely on the function you're calling (or object you're instantiating).

For instance, `print()` accepts the arguments to print (or none to just print a new line):

```
>>> print()

>>> print("hello")
hello
>>> print("hello", 42)
hello 42
>>>
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of what would go in the parentheses? Thanks!

Comment: I can give you the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/turtle.html#turtle.pen

Comment: @AKX, that's the wrong documentation.  There is a `pen` (lowercase)method and a `Pen` (uppercase) class name alias, which is what the OP invoked.  The documentation you cited is for the method.  The only mention of the class alias in the documentation is "Derived from RawTurtle is the subclass Turtle (alias: Pen)"